# Add library with 2 platform using CoCoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, shared-libraries, cocoapods

I can’t import Instructions into my project via cocoa pods because my project still use platform 6.0.

So i need import Instruction (platform: 8.0) https://github.com/ephread/Instructions , how can i add. instructions into target iPadPOS.

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want to import to iPadPOS?

Comment: I edited my question. Can you have me @Tapani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your project is targeted to iOS 6 and you try to use a library, which uses iOS 8 features then you cannot use that library in your project. It uses apis, which are not available in iOS 6 or 7. You have to change your app to require iOS 8+.